# Sharepoint 2013: Repeated user authentification in Outlook

Tags: 2013, outlook, contacts

I've searched for this for quite a time and haven't found a solution yet, so I hope you guys can maybe help meout here.

Im running Sharepoint 2013 in our buisness enviroment and everything works fine - except synchronisation with outlook.

What I'm trying to do is: Creating a Sharepoint Contact-List and sync it with Outlook and have it open for specific users only. For this List I want to break the right-transmission, since some users should only be allowed to hae permission to this list, but not the site.

Now the List is done, right-transmission-break is done, sync is done - but i get the user-authentification-window every time I open Outlook and try to enter this list. I tried to put myself in various authorization-groups, I get the same result everytime. Only exeption here is, if I put myself as the site-colletion-administrator, which is ofc not the purpose of my goal here. Anonymus access is not what i need here btw.

Version of Outlook is 2019 and 2013.

If anyone here might have an idea to get rid of the repeated userauth.prompts, i would be happy to try them.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed.

I had to edit Intranetsites in the IExplorer via GPO's. Problem here was I had my sharepoint site entry in "trusted sites" like ".domain", where it was requiered like this "*.domain" to solve my Problem. I dont know why i couldn't edit it in the trusted sites.